# Integral of differential forms vs orientability

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\omega$ be an $n$-form on an $n$-manifold $M$, and $F: M\to M$ be a diffeomorphism. Here for simplicity let $\phi:U\to S$ and $\psi:V\to T$ be two charts of $M$ such that $F(U) = V$.

I believe we have the definition $\int_U \omega = \int_S (\phi^{-1})^* \omega$, and similar for $\int_V \omega$.

I believe we have $\int_U F^* \omega = \pm \int_V \omega$, positive if $F$ is orientation-preserving, and negative otherwise. I am attempting to understand the this equality.

Let $x^k$ be the local coordinates on $U$, and $y^k$ be that on $V$. Write $\omega = \omega_{12...n} dx^1 \wedge dx^2  \wedge \cdots \wedge 
dx^n$ on $U$ and $\omega = \omega_{12...n}' dy^1 \wedge dy^2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy^n$ on $V$.

Also let $f: S\to T$ be the local representation of $F$.

To make things absolutely clear, I am also going to write $s^k$ for coordinates on $S$, and $t^k$ for that on $T$.

Now 
$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_U F^* \omega &= \int_S (\phi^{-1})^* F^* \omega \\
&= \int_S f^* (\psi^{-1})^* \omega \\
&= \int_S f^* (\omega_{12...n}'\circ \psi^{-1} dt^1 \wedge dt^2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dt^n) \\
&= \int_S (\omega_{12...n}'\circ \psi^{-1} \circ f) \det(df) \cdot ds^1 \wedge ds^2 \wedge \cdots \wedge ds^n \\
&= \int_S (\omega_{12...n}'\circ \psi^{-1} \circ f(s)) \det(df)(s) \cdot ds^1 ds^2 \dots ds^n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$

Then by multivariable calculus the above becomes 
$\text{sign}\det(df) \int_T \omega_{12...n}'\circ \psi^{-1} (t) \cdot dt^1 dt^2 \dots dt^n 
= \text{sign}\det(df) \int_T (\psi^{-1})^* \omega 
= \text{sign}\det(df) \int_V \omega$.

If everything so far is correct, then $\text{sign}\det(df)$ should correspond to whether $F$ is orientation-preserving.

But what if I change the chart $\psi$ to $\psi_0: V\to T_0$, where $\psi_0 (v)$ switches the first two coordinates of $\psi(v)$? Then we have a new set of coordinates $z^k$ on $V$ and $u^k$ on $T_0$, new expression $\omega = \omega_{12...n}'' dz^1 \wedge dz^2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dz^n$ on $V$, and a new local representation $f_0: S\to T_0$ of $F$.

We do the exact same computation as before. From what I can see nothing seems to break, and we still get $\int_U F^* \omega = \text{sign}\det(df_0) \int_V \omega$.

But $df_0$ switches the first two columns of $df$, so $\det(df_0)$ and $\det(df)$ must have different signs.

This seems to be not great. For the life of me I couldn't figure out where exactly things went wrong.

Comment: That is precisely why, in the definition of integration of differential forms, you have to choose an *oriented* chart. This resolves the sign ambiguity in the definition. The other part is noting that a diffeomorphism pulls a chart back to a chart, but it can pull back a positively oriented chart to a negatively oriented chart (precisely if it reverses orientation there) and that yields the other sign you've observed. These are really two instances of the same fundamental phenomenon (e.g. take $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $F$ switch the first two coordinates).

Comment: Oh so the problem is that my definition is slightly lacking. Thanks a lot!